# Install linux/bsd on compact flash using USB connector

Tags: linux, embedded, bsd, grub

How do I install linux/bsd on compact flash with usb compact flash adapter. The compact flash will boot on single board x86 computer as an IDE drive, but I'm doing the install on a regular computer using a usb to compact flash adaptor, thus the compact flash shows up as a USB device instead of as a IDE device, so I can't get lilo to pick it up as hda because it is recognized as usb so I can't get lilo to read the lilo.conf. I would pretty much know what to do if I had a pcmcia adaptor to plug the compact flash into another computer and get recognized as a regular hardrive. Also take in mind the install needs to be under 512mb.

Comment: There are other StackExchange sites about Linux or computer software where this question may fit, but it does not fit on StackOverflow, because it isn't about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried PlOP boot manager?  It's a CD that forces computers to boot from a USB stick.  It doesn't ALWAYS work but it's good.  More info at http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16822/boot-from-a-usb-drive-even-if-your-bios-wont-let-you/  I'd recommend Puppy Linux for a solid, small, and simple Linux distro -- i'm not well acquainted with BSD.

Comment: Read [this meta post](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330), you must.